# Erlang. Connecting to local node: *** ERROR: Shell process terminated

Tags: erlang

i have been struggling to connect to erlang node and with no luck.
The situation is following:

1) I have "-detached" erlang node running on local host with `-sname n1`

2)

```
$ epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name n1 at port 53653
```

3) Trying to connect

```
$ erl -sname test -remsh n1
...
ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job)


$ erl -sname test -setcookie *COOKIE* -remsh n1
...
ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job)


$ erl -sname test -setcookie *COOKIE* -remsh n1@localhost
...
ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job)
```

What else should i try ?

**UPD:**

Following @Odobenus Rosmarus advice:

```
$ hostname
server.domain.com
$ erl -sname test -setcookie *COOKIE* -remsh n1@server.domain.com
** System NOT running to use fully qualified hostnames **
** Hostname server.domain.com is illegal **
** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) **
```

another blind try (throw away part of fqdn):

```
$ erl -sname test -setcookie *COOKIE* -remsh n1@server
Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
(ipspy@server)1>
```

Ok, in 5 tries we are there, cool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
erl -sname test -setcookie *COOKIE* -remsh n1@hostname
```

where *hostname* is not localhost, but  output of 'hostname' command on your computer.